# Problems with all the windows opening separately in QT4

Tags: qt4, qtablewidget, qlistwidget

I am new to QT, right now am trying to place a Table below a QList, but the Qlist and the table are showing as two separate window. I need the output more or less like itunes with the Qlist on top and a Qtable at the bottom.

Any Help is Appreciated. Below are the codes for all the files. thanks

```
//main.cpp
#include "listwidget.h"
#include "table.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);  

  ListWidget window;
  Table window2;    


  window.move(300, 300);
  window.setWindowTitle("Qtunes");
  window.show();

//  window2.move(300, 300);
 /// window2.setWindowTitle("Qtunes");
  window2.show();   

  return app.exec();
}


//Listwidget.cpp
#include "listwidget.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QInputDialog>


ListWidget::ListWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

  QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);

  lw = new QListWidget(this);
  lw2 = new QListWidget(this);  
  lw3 = new QListWidget(this); 

  hbox->addWidget(lw);

  hbox->addWidget(lw2);

  hbox->addWidget(lw3);


  setLayout(hbox);
}







//listwidget.h
#ifndef LISTWIDGET_H
#define LISTWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QListWidget>

class ListWidget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    ListWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

  private:
    QListWidget *lw;
    QListWidget *lw2;
    QListWidget *lw3;   

};



#endif







//table.h
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include <QWidget>

class Table : public QWidget
{
  public:
    Table(QWidget *parent2 = 0);

};

#endif






//table.cpp
#include "table.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTableWidget>

Table::Table(QWidget *parent2)
    : QWidget(parent2)
{
  QHBoxLayout *hbox2 = new QHBoxLayout(this);

  QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(25, 25, this);

  hbox2->addWidget(table);
  setLayout(hbox2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a window first, and then make the table and list children of that window. The top-level window can be a simple QWidget, or a QMainWindow if you need the extra functionality provided by it (like menus, tool bars, status bar, etc.) If you use a QMainWindow, you should still use another widget, set that as the QMainWindow's central widget (setCentralWidget()) and then add the list and table to that central widget.

For even better results, you can also put them both in a layout.

The thing to keep in mind is that widgets without a parent will always be top-level windows.